# Como escrever dentro de uma borda com imagem

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá gostaria de escrever dentro da borda mas não consegui segue meu codigo

```css
.first-row-sites .img-responsive, .form-sites-container, .second-row-sites .img-responsive {
    border-top: 50px solid #006400;
   border-radius: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="second-row-sites">


<a title="Clique para acessar" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/495197/0st9yhngses-benjamin-child.jpg"> <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/495197/0st9yhngses-benjamin-child.jpg" alt="Carta de Serviços da Saúde" /> </a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc realmente quer escrever algo ali, ou vc quer fazer ou menu, ou colocar um link ou botão que seja? Ou apenas que colocar um texto qualquer?

Comment: colocar um texto qualquer

Comment: Coloque o elemento que você quer por exemplo <p> em position absolute e mova ele com left e top para ajustar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se é isso que vc quer mesmo... Vc pode criar um pseudo elemento no seu link, onde a imagem está dentro e nesse pseudo elemento vc escreve o texto que vc quer. Na verdade ele vai estar no link, mas vai dar a impressão que está dentro da borda da imagem.

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.first-row-sites .img-responsive,
.form-sites-container,
.second-row-sites .img-responsive {
    border-top: 50px solid #006400;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
a::after {
  content: 'meu texto aqui';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left:5px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="second-row-sites">
                <a title="Clique para acessar" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/495197/0st9yhngses-benjamin-child.jpg"> 
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/495197/0st9yhngses-benjamin-child.jpg" alt="Carta de Serviços da Saúde" /> 
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo pois uso wordpress e quando eu coloco o css ele replica em todas as paginas, teria que ser especifico pra essa div se não vai para todas as paginas.

Comment: @Ludi então coloca um ID nesse link fipo `<a id="texto" href="..."><img></a>` e no CSS coloque as propriedade em `#texto { css }` Isso vai fazer o CSS ser aplicado apenas no elemento que tem o ` id="texto" `. Minha resposta é um exemplo pra te ajudar, se vc tivesse deixado claro na resposta que é para apenas uma imagem em uma página de wordpress etc, eu já poderia ter incluído esses detalhes na resposta não no comentário aqui, mas espero que ajude com essa dica

Comment: nem consegui, mas obrigaod.

Comment: @Ludi se vc fizer uma pergunta com um ambiente mais perto do real que vc tem ai talvez eu possa ajudar... mas se vc quer que o CSS só funciona para um elemento em particular, ou ele tem que ter uma classe que só ele tem, ou ele tem que ter um ID ai vc coloca o seletor do CSS para um #ID e não para uma .Classe